# Microsoft Bot Framework: did they change naming conventions between 2018 and 2020?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I'm trying to learn Chatbox programming with the Microsoft Bot Framework.  I bought a book from 2018 titled "Programming the Microsoft Bot Framework" by Joe Mayo.  I feel the book is an easy read and was giving me a good background, but when I try to do the examples using Visual Studio 2019 the names of the methods in the book don't match the ones produced by visual studio, and so now I'm confused.

**Book**: They start a project using the "Bot Application" template, with the entry point to the  chatbox being a file in the Controllers folder called "MessageController.cs".  The file contains a method `public async Task <HttpResponseMessage> Post(Activity activity)`

**Latest version of Bot Framework with VS 2019:**  There is no "Bot Application" template, but rather the choice to select a new "EchoBot", "EmptyBot", or "CoreBot".  In all 3 choices, "MessageController.cs" is not present in the file list, but instead there is a "BotController.cs" file.  This file does not come with a Post function, but rather has `public async Task PostAsync()`

I'm fine with the different template choices between versions, but confused as to if there's a difference between PostAsync and Post methods?  Are these just new naming conventions?  Is the framework significantly different between 2018 and 2020?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bot Framework has significantly changed between version 3 and version 4. November 2019, [the Bot Framework V4 SDK went generally available](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/microsoft-bot-framework-v4-sdk-is-now-generally-available/).

The following documentation could help understanding the differences between v3 and v4 bots.

- [Migration overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/migration-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)
- [Differences between the v3 and v4 .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/migration-about?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
- [Migrate a .NET v3 bot to a .NET Framework v4 bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/conversion-framework?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
- [Migrate a .NET v3 bot to a .NET Core v4 bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/conversion-core?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: Too bad.  I liked the book I was reading.  I find the tutorial/documentation that Microsoft puts out hard to understand for a novice with bots.  There doesn't appear to be any books on v4 yet.